# Significance/Need of setting the properties to nil in viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, memory-management, properties, null, significance

- What is the significance of setting the properties to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` in both the aspects i.e. with ARC or without ARC?
- Does it only matter in case of `IBOulets`? Don't we need to set the other properties (that are not `IBOulets`) to `nil`?
- What can be the consequences if I don't do that? I haven't set them `nil` before and haven't observe any consequences.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA, so we can't directly discuss it quite yet. But I recommend searching for "viewDidUnload" in the iOS 6 Release Notes. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html (I know this question wasn't about iOS 6, but this will tell you Apple's recommendations for the method.)

Answer (score 1):

Setting IBOutlets to nil in viewDidUnload tells the compiler to release the outlets on memory warning.because on memory warning ..viewDidUnload and didReceiveMemoryWarning of the viewcontrollers gets called..Normally in ViewDidUnload the IBOutlets are set to nil and in didReceiveMemoryWarning properties or objects are released.Hence in such a case memory is regained and thus your app can continue to function else continuous pooling causes in crash due to low memory

Comment: Did you mean that it has nothing to deal with ARC?

Comment: if you have declared a property of IBOutlet as retain or (strong in ARC) then you need to release it in viewDidUnload.But if the the property assigned to IBOutlet is assign or (weak in ARC), then there's no need to set the outlets to nil

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot articles on the web and going through similar questions on stackoverflow.com I reached at the following understanding:

- `viewDidUnload` is called by the compiler in low memory situation.
- We should set those properties to nil in the method, which are being re-instanciated in `viewDidLoad`. Almost all IBOutlet components falls under the category. So better we declare the IBOutlets to nil in the method. Not doing so will lead to continuous pooling and may cause crash due to low memory in future(the time, the app continues to run).
- I also read that we should not nil the instances of the class like NSString(may cause crash), which is right as per my experience. But reason for that I don't know.
- It has nothing to deal with ARC. Setting a property to nil simply means that the property doesnot keep the refrence of any memory location anymore.

I will keep on updating this answer every time i came to know something more about it.

Thanks.